how to convert app-no-VR to app-VR in unity
the game is simple, a graphical interface with several menus in the form of buttons where you can change the size or color of the font or the background of the interface, the lighting..... with an object that you can change this texture change its position zoom-in and zoom-out...., yes I use the htc vive and steamvr vr headset and camera rig I was able to display the graphical interface and the object on the headset vr but I can't do the interaction with the controllers that's what I wanted to know HOW TO DO THAT. I have already done that the user interface and the object + the controllers all are displayed on the VR headset but the problems are the interactions with the controllers I don't know how to make them work I'm a little beginner on unity for example before entering the vr I click with the mouse on menu after a submenu will be displayed I click on font for example and I increase the size or I change the color but now how to do that with the controllers. is i need to change in old scripts or just do configurations.really i need help if anyone can help me i would be very grateful .

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You should look up a tutorial on Youtube. Most likely you want to use OpenXR with the XR Interaction Toolkit package. Maybe you can look for some videos from Dilmer Valecillos.
